# jQuery animate scrollTo not working on click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Been a long day so i guess or rather know im making a stupid mistake here but can anyone see what?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ehv1hyco/3/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function scrollToTab(tabScrollTo){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(tabScrollTo).offset().top - 15 }, 2000);
  }

  $('#tab_description h6 a').on("click, tap", function(){
    scrollToTab($(this).attr('href'));
  });

});
```

the fiddle and above js is just a mockup from a larger piece of code to simplify this question - so markup of html is correct with what is generated from the cms

Here is the whole JS if needed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var originalTabs = $('.originalTabs').html();
  var windowWidth = 0;

  function clearTabs() {
    $('.originalTabs').html(originalTabs);
  }

  //clearTabs();
  //desktopTabs(); 

  function desktopTabs() {
    clearTabs();

    // cretate tabs for desktop
    var headers = $("#tab_description h6");

    $('#tab_description h6').each(function(i) {
      $(this).nextUntil("h6").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="tab" id="tab-' + i + '"/>');
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
      $('.tabs').append('<li class=""><a href="#tab-' + i + '">' + headers[i].innerHTML + '</a></li>');
    }

    $('ul.tabs').each(function() {
      var active, content, links = $(this).find('a');
      var listitem = $(this).find('li');
      active = listitem.first().addClass('active');
      content = $(active.attr('href'));
      $('.tab').hide();
      $(this).find('a').click(function(e) {
        $('.tab').hide();
        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
        content.hide();
        active = $(this);
        content = $($(this).attr('href'));
        active.parent().addClass('active');
        content.show();
        return false;
      });
    });

    headers.remove(); // remove headers from description  
    $('#tab-0').show(); // show the first tab
  }

  function mobileTabs() {
    clearTabs();

    //alert("loaded mobile");

    var headers = $("#tab_description h6");

    $(headers).each(function(i) {
      $(this).append('<a href="#accordion_' + (i + 1) + '" id="accordion_' + (i + 1) + '"></a>');
      //$(this).nextUntil("h6").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="aTab" id="tab-'+i+'"/>');
      $(this).on('click', function() {
        tabClick($(this));
      });
    });

    $('#tab_description h6').first().trigger('click').addClass("active");
    $('#tab_description h6').first().nextUntil("h6").show();
  }

  var tabClick = function(x) {

    //alert("clicked");
    var accordionContent = $('#tab_description p, #tab_description ul, #tab_description table, #tab_description div');

    $('#tab_description h6').removeClass("active");
    if (!$(x).hasClass("active")) {
      $(x).addClass("active");
    }

    // Check if current accordion item is open
    var isOpen = $(x).next().is(":visible");

    // Hide all accordion items
    accordionContent.hide();

    //console.log(x);
    // Open accordion item if previously closed
    if (!isOpen) {
      $(x).nextUntil('h6').show();
      $(x).nextUntil(accordionContent).show();
    }

    //console.log($(x).find('a').attr('href'));

  }

  function scrollToTab(tabScrollTo){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(tabScrollTo).offset().top - 15 }, 2000);
  }

  //load default
  $(window).on("load",function(){

    if (isMobileLandscapeOnly.matches || isTabletLandscapeOnly.matches) {
      //alert("Mobile / Tablet (Portrait)");
      desktopTabs();
      //$('#tab_description h6').on("click, tap", tabClick);

      //console.log(originalTabs);
    } else if (isMobilePortraitOnly.matches || isTabletPortraitOnly.matches) {
      //alert("Mobile / Tablet (Portrait)");
      mobileTabs();
      //$('#tab_description h6').on("click, tap", tabClick);

    } else if (isDesktop) {
      //alert("Desktop");
      desktopTabs();
    }
  });

  //bind to resize
  $(window).on("orientationchange resize",function(){

    if(windowWidth != $(window).width()){

      if (isMobileLandscapeOnly.matches || isTabletLandscapeOnly.matches) {
        desktopTabs();
        $('#tab_description h6').on("click, tap", tabClick);

      } else if (isMobilePortraitOnly.matches || isTabletPortraitOnly.matches) {
        mobileTabs();
        $('#tab_description h6').on("click, tap", tabClick);

      } else if (isDesktop) {
        desktopTabs();
      }

      windowWidth = $(window).width();
      delete windowWidth;

    }

  });

  $('#tab_description h6 a').on("click, tap", function(){
    scrollToTab($(this).attr('href'));
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The on click event was not working due to my tabClick function so i called the function within that... only issue is it was scrolling down on page load and was due to the following:

```
$('#tab_description h6').first().trigger('click').addClass("active");
```

changing to

```
$('#tab_description h6').first().addClass("active");
```

resolved that issue so all working

Answer (score 0):

My good friend,

Your issue lies in the .on() event.  You have to specify the parameters individually so it should look like this instead:

```
$('#tab_description h6 a').on("click", "tap", function(){
    scrollToTab($(this).attr('href'));
  });
```

Notice both click and tap have a separate set of parenthesis? This should solve your problem. Can't say why this is different than how you target multiple elements but I'm sure the JQuery gurus had a good reason. Cheers.

Comment: Giving it a go now, i have added the full JS to the question if you need a better look at it all :)

Comment: Did not seem to work, i added console.log('clicked'); as well and did not show in console for some reason.

Comment: Think it might be confliting with my tabClick function as i add console.log('clicked'); in that and shows when i click... i could add the scrollToTab function in there and would work but i would need to prevent it calling scrollToTab on initial page load and only when physically clicked

Comment: Fixed it, will post solution

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('#tab_description h6 a').on("click tap", function(){
    scrollToTab($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: Think it might be confliting with my tabClick function as i add console.log('clicked'); in that and shows when i click... i could add the scrollToTab function in there and would work but i would need to prevent it calling scrollToTab on initial page load and only when physically clicked

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function scrollToTab(tabScrollTo){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(tabScrollTo).offset().top - 15 }, 2000);
  }

  // not on("click, tap", ...
  // but on("click tap", ...
  $('#tab_description h6 a').on("click, tap", function(){
    scrollToTab($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

**added** 
i read your full code. perhaps this will help.

```
$(window).on("load",function(){
  ....

  // add this to the last
  $('#tab_description h6 a').on("click, tap", function(){
    scrollToTab($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});


$(window).on("orientationchange resize",function(){
  ...

  // add this to the last
  $('#tab_description h6 a').on("click, tap", function(){
    scrollToTab($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```